# change image cache size

Tags: image, product-images

Address url for images is [this](http://www.timports.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/400x400/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/k/i/kiln-driedlogs20.jpg)

I've uploaded 3 images in admin thumbnail, small image and base image.
None of the images I've uploaded is 400x400.

I can see that its cached, how can I stop the cache setting to 400x400

Answer (score 1):

Go to the **admin panel -> System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Developer -> Debug -> Template Path Hints** and select **Yes** (before this you have to change **Current Configuration Scope** to your website). Don't forget to fill in your IP in **Developer Client Restrictions**. After this refresh your cache. Then open your product list and see which template is used (most probably it's something like this: **template/catalog/product/list.phtml**). In this file search for `resize` (most probably it will be `resize(400)`) and change it to `resize(155)`.